# The `success` method has been deprecated. Use the `then` method instead

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am new to Vue world and here is the warning I get:
The success method has been deprecated. Use the then method instead.

And here is the code:

```
apiURL = 'api/movies';

new Vue({
   el: '#app',

   data: {
      'movies': ''
   },

   ready: function() {
      this.getMovies();
   },

   methods: {
      getMovies: function() {
         this.$http.get(apiURL, function(movies) {
            this.$set('movies', movies);
         });
      }
   }
});
```

Also is this a right method to do this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```js
this.$http.get('/').then(function (response) {
    this.$set('movies', response.data);
}
```

All in all, `vue-resource` is somewhat buggy and unpolished. If you use the latest version, the only explanation would be that developer used his own deprecated method. Namely, `success` instead of `then`.

Comment: This works but then I need to use `v-for="movie in movies.data` insted of `v-for="movie in movies`

Answer (score 1):

Your GET request should be using the `then` promise like so:

```
this.$http.get(apiURL).then(function (movies) {
    this.$set('movies', movies);
});
```

Just as shown in the vue-resource read-me page: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource#example

The deprecation warning is coming from this line: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/ed85a38a1c88faf4e1ac1d7c15cca8376aa933c8/dist/vue-resource.js#L853

To answer your last question, there is nothing inherently wrong with your methods.

Comment: This works but then I need to use `v-for="movie in movies.data` insted of `v-for="movie in movies"`

Comment: @user3806764 once you set the movies to your data property, you can use the v-for directive to list every movie in movies. http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html. Otherwise you can use a normal JavaScript for loop to iterate through the movies.